# Why is the led that I hooked up with my laptop blinking?

Tags: led, usb, wire

I connected a led to my laptop through a USB cable. I connected the red wire to the positive end of the LED and the black wire to the negative and of the LED. Why does the led keep blinking (pulsing) instead of emitting light continuously?

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a LED, no resistor? What type of LED?

Comment: I'm using a potentiometer too, but it's the same with or without. I mean the leds don't burn out. I've just connected another led in series with the other one. If I turn the potentiometer counter clock-wise the leds start to toggle blink. Really funny.

Comment: Is it a power led? How fast is it blinking? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have a chip inside at least one of those LEDs that you can't see causing it to blink. Hook it up to a battery and resistor to make sure.

Comment: I did what you said, and it was still blinking; it must be an internal thing.

Answer (score 3):

It keeps blinking because you are trying to draw infinite current from the USB and the computer is disabling the port.

The resistance of an LED is 0Ω. The current I is V/R.  USB is 5V. 5/0 = infinity.

If the computer didn't shut off the power your LED would melt.

You need a current limiting resistor in there.  Get the forward voltage of the LED (read its data sheet) and the forward current limit.  Assuming 2V and 20mA (common values), resistance would be (R=V/I) = (5 - 2) / 0.02 = 150Ω.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqqkI1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm using a potentiometer before the leds. I've only got an 680 Ohm resistor right now. Will that be ok?

Comment: You could have mentioned that in your question...  How about providing a schematic?  680Ω will work, the LED just won't be as bright.

Comment: I substituted the potentiometer with a 680 Ohm resistor but it's still blinking. I did exact as the above schematic depicts.

Comment: Then it could be that your computer is trying to detect a real USB device on the port and failing, so it disables the port.  You may need resistors on the USB data lines. There's different arrangements and different specifications for different currents. Simplest is a 200Ω resistor between D+ and D-. Google for "USB battery charger resistors" for lots of different variations.

Comment: If a added a capacitor to the circuit would that solve the problem?

Comment: No.  It sounds like you most probably need those resistors.

Comment: I'm 100% that it's not due to the laptop. I have connected the USB cable to an AC phone charger travel adapter (it's a kind of charger that has usb output) and it's still blinking.

Comment: Oh?  Maybe... you have a blinking LED?

Comment: Is there such thing? Do they manufacture blinking leds?

Comment: Yes, they do. They have a little chip embedded in them that makes them blink.  Examine the LED closely and look for a little black bit inside it.

Comment: Nope, it has no chip in it. I also connected a pc fan and that works just find.

Comment: Do you have a 9V PP3 battery handy? Try the LED (with the 680Ω resistor) on that battery.  If it still blinks then you must have a blinking LED.

Comment: How is the resistance of an LED 0Ω?

Comment: It's a semiconductor. It has a voltage drop, but it doesn't have a resistance as such (maybe a few mΩ from the wires).

Comment: To be more specific, it's a "non-linear device". There isn't a straight relationship between current and voltage with them - at the forward threshold voltage the current conduction goes from very little to very large - as if the resistance drops from very large to almost nothing. Google: "diode graph" and check images.

Comment: I did what you all suggested and hooked up the led to a 680 Ohm resistor and a battery. It is still blinking so I guess it must be made this way. I'm happy I didn't bought a lot of it.

Comment: But, wouldn't this answer imply that USB supply impedance is also 0Ω in order for an infinite amount of current to flow?

Comment: Now you're just being pedantic.

Comment: @Majenko Really not trying to be, sorry if it sounds like that. I connected a green LED (no resistor) to a bench supply adjusted to ~2V, which I limited to 500mA. When I connected the LED, it did not hit the current limit. Even at 5V USB voltage, it drew 180mA, turned orange and slowly died. (Before it died, I sprayed it with freeze spray for science; it turned yellow!) How could the LED draw enough current for the computer to disable the port? If the LED drew infinite current when forward biased, why didn't the bench supply hit the current limit?

Comment: There are inherent resistances in the wires, pins, connections, etc.  Not that much, true, but it is there - 0Ω is the holy grail of superconductors.  Also no LED is a "perfect" LED. Yes, the supply has impedance that limits the current it can send out. Oh, and unless the device negotiates for > 100mA, 180mA is (or should be) classed as an overload and the port shut off.  A "perfect" LED with a zero impedance supply and 0Ω superconducting wires will draw infinity amps. In the real world it is considerably less.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify how did you connect the LED!

If the LED is consistently blinking at the same frequency, you may have a LED with internal flashing circuit. These are not very common though but they are [available](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/led-4g/green-flasher-led-t-1/3/4/1.html).

If the LED is getting warm and flashing at an irregular interval it may be drawing too much power from the USB port. Although USB ports are fused, this may damage the LED and/or the USB port.